# How to get output of -interpreter-exec in GDB/MI?

Tags: c++, c, linux, gdb

I'm writing a wrapper for GDB/MI, however, I miss some commands in the MI interface. For example, the 'info variables' command. I can execute it with "-interpreter-exec console", but getting the output of it is tricky since it writes everything to console records and not to the result record. So I decided to just take every console record between prompt ("(gdb) " line) and "^done" record, concatenate them, and return as a result. My question is — is this safe? It seems that this approach is error-prone, but I don't have any other idea. Ideas?

**UPDATE:**
Also, it might be useful to use python like this `-interpreter-exec console "python\nprint(gdb.execute('info variables', False, True))\n"` and the results will appear in one line which is nice, but still how do I get exactly this line safely? Maybe I should prepend it with some token... Anyway, it seems that the third argument of `gdb.execute` is not commonly supported, so relying on it may not be a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, in fact `gdb.execute` with the third argument is actually supported in gdb 7.3 which is dated 2011, so I guess using it is fine. So I decided to go with this command

```
import gdb
import sys


class ConcatCommand(gdb.Command):
    """Executes a command and print concatenated results with a prefix."""

def __init__(self):
    super(ConcatCommand, self).__init__("concat", gdb.COMMAND_USER)

def invoke(self, arg, from_tty):
    pair = arg.partition(' ')
    sys.stdout.write(pair[0] + gdb.execute(pair[2], False, True))
    sys.stdout.flush()

ConcatCommand()
```

Execute it like `-interpreter-exec console "concat token info variables"`. Then I just take the contents of console record that starts with a token.